# How to prevent expose any other interface methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, interface

I have one interface like below

```
public interface I1 
{
public int add(int a , int b);

public int subtract (int a, int b);

}

public class Myclass : I1
{
//here I can access both the methods of interface I1
//add and subtract but i want to expose only add not subtract method
//How can I achieve this? 

}
```

How can I expose only particular method and prevent other.

Comment: You can't prevent it, but you can "hide" the method on type `Myclass` (but not type `I1`) with [Explicit interface implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(v=vs.71).aspx): "*An explicit interface member implementation can only be accessed through an interface instance*, and is in that case referenced simply by its member name."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the method by explicit implementation. I'd say its a bad idea and you should probably split your interface in two instead, but it is possible

```
public class MyClass {
    public int I1.subtract(int a, int b) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When done like this subtract will only be visible when the `object` is **cast as I1**

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of requirement go for Abstract class not interface because in interface all methods are public by default., that is one of the difference between Abstract class and interface.

In interface you cannnot put modfier like private and public, all the methods are public by default.

Answer (score 1):

the concept of interface says that you `if you implement an interface you need to implement all the methods` so I think it can't be done
Further more the default methods of `interface` are `public`

So when you are going to defining it, it should be `public` only.

Here is a link for better understanding of `Interfaces`
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners

Here is a link which depicts the difference between `Interface` and `abstract class`
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need such behavior. If you just want one of the methods to be available to the MyClass object, you can use explicit interface implementation for that particular method

```
public class Myclass : I1
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public int I1.subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

In this case when you create an object of MyClass, you will have only add method, not subtract. To access subtract, you will have to use the reference type of I1